# C# How to use LINQ to grab all cell data under a particular column header name

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

Given a list of column header names, I want to parse an HTML table using HTMLAgilityPack, to retrieve all table data under that column.

I can't seem to figure out how to apply LINQ towards this.

I am grabbing the table header column names like so...

```
//Select HTML Table
var table = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table");
List<string> headerColumnNames = new List<string>();

foreach (HtmlNode tableHeader in table.SelectNodes("tr[1]/th"))
{
   headerColumnNames.Add(tableHeader.InnerText.Trim());              
}
```

(If you know how to do this in LINQ please feel free to give me an example).

Now I want to do something like

```
foreach (string name in headerColumnNames){

//SELECT all table data 
//WHERE the table column.name == name
//return a List of strings representing each cell value

}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this using LINQ.

Comment: What does the HTML look like, and what kind of output data are you after? Please post examples.

Comment: I don't think you should even use Linq for this because HtmlAgilityPack does not implement a Linq query provider. HtmlAgilityPack is old and hasn't been significantly updated in almost a decade (e.g. it doesn't support `querySelector`). Is there a reason you're not using a more up-to-date library like AngleSharp?

Comment: I wasn't aware of AngleSharp, thanks for the information. I will look into it.

Comment: Not sure how to make the second query. I imagine you can filter by column name and get the column index with something like that `.Select((th, index) => new { Name = th.InnerText, Column = index })` then match it to `td` index. But the index for `td` need to reset for each `tr`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var headerColumnNames = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]")
    .SelectNodes("./thead[1]/tr[1]/th/text()")
    .Select(th => th.InnerText.Trim());
```